# Required custom code in HP UFT APITest to execute or run a service call activity

Tags: c#, hp-uft

We are trying to create Keyword driven Framework for API Test using HP UFT tool.
We are aware that basic custom codes in C# to transfer values, store xmls, accessing excel sheet to read test data and write reports, adding report event and check point rules.

The APITestsuite becomes more complex while adding more scenarios in the API Test suite. So we plan to create more generic framework using C# custom code make reusable methods and properties with keyword driven through excel sheet.

I can't find the way to execute / run particular service call activity through custom code, like in SOAP-UI groovy code "Run TestStep". Searched lot in google but no luck.

Please share if you have link for UFT best practice API automation framework  also.

Thanks,
Madhan

Comment: Depending on how you have Excel sheet created for it and how you are loadning it into UFT, but if you add a column with execution flag would give you control on execution.

Comment: Yes Manish, we tried that method but the thing is we required to add more if statements [ for 10 service calls / steps we have to add 10 if statements ] to check the execution flag and the test flow again becomes complex.

Comment: How you are handling Excel file?

Comment: We can import excel sheet inside APITest and data paramaterized on service calls in test flow. Have one column to set flag for each service call. In IF conditon statement in TestFlow is paramaterized with that column to checking the flag set as YES or NO.